# Porque me dice que insert tiene mas expresiones que columnas de destino?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Espero puedan ayudarme soy nuevo en esto...

```
CREATE DATABASE mundial
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'Spanish_Spain.1252'
    LC_CTYPE = 'Spanish_Spain.1252'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;


CREATE SEQUENCE usuario_seq;    
    CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    id_usuario SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEXTVAL('usuario_seq'),
    usuario VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    contrasena VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    tipo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    estado BOOLEAN
);

INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario, contrasena, tipo, estado) VALUES('admin','123','administrador',TRUE);
INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario, contrasena, tipo, estado) VALUES('AMLO','135','administrador',TRUE);
INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario, contrasena, tipo, estado) VALUES('cisco','456','invitado',TRUE);
INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario, contrasena, tipo, estado) VALUES('hansolo','789','invitado',TRUE);


CREATE TABLE jugador(
   id_jugador SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
   nombre VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   apellidop VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   apellidom VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   fecha_nac DATE NOT NULL,
   id_posicion VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
```

**Este el el primer error**

> ERROR:  el valor null para la columna «id_jugador» viola la
>   restricción not null
>       DETAIL:  La fila que falla contiene (null, Cristiano, Ronaldo, dos santos, 1985-02-05, delantero).

```
INSERT INTO jugador(nombre, apellidop, apellidom, fecha_nac, id_posicion) VALUES('Cristiano','Ronaldo','dos santos','05/02/1985','delantero');
INSERT INTO jugador(nombre, apellidop, apellidom, fecha_nac, id_posicion) VALUES('Francisco Guillermo','Ochoa','Magaña','13/07/1985','portero');
INSERT INTO jugador(nombre, apellidop, apellidom, fecha_nac, id_posicion) VALUES('Neymar','Da silva','Santos','05/02/1995','medio');
INSERT INTO jugador(nombre, apellidop, apellidom, fecha_nac, id_posicion) VALUES('Sergio','Ramos','Garcia','30/03/1986','defensa');
INSERT INTO jugador(nombre, apellidop, apellidom, fecha_nac, id_posicion) VALUES('Arturo','Vidal','Pardo','22/05/1987','defensa');

CREATE TABLE posicion(
    id_posicion VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    des_posicion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

> ERROR:  INSERT tiene más expresiones que columnas de destino
>       LINE 1: ...SERT INTO posicion(des_posicion) VALUES('portero','defensa',...

```
INSERT INTO posicion(des_posicion) VALUES('portero','defensa','medio','delantero');
```

Comment: Parece que no tienes muy claro la cuestión de las llaves primarias. En la tabla `jugador` la llave primaria debería ser declarada al menos así: `id_jugador  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`, así irá aumentando en cada inserción.   Lo mismo debería ocurrir en la tabla `posicion`. O, si no quieres un número que se auto-incremente, entonces debes incluir el valor de forma explícita en el `INSERT INTO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes **varios errores en tu modelo de datos**.

Los enumero aquí según he ido viendo y al final de propongo una corrección.

- Declara las llaves primarias auto-incrementales como `SERIAL`, de ese modo vas a delegar las secuencias al manejador y no tendrás que preocuparte de nada más.
- En la tabla `jugador` debe existir una relación con la columna `id_posicion` de la tabla `posiciones`, la cual puede ser también auto-incremental y no `varchar`.
- En el `INSERT INTO` de la tabla `jugador` debes usar el valor numérico de la posición, no el varchar. Eso te puede traer muchos errores.
- En la misma tabla `jugadores` estás introduciendo las fechas de nacimiento con un formato equivocado. Debes usar el formato `Año-Mes-Dia` siempre que vayas a guardar datos en la BD, de lo contrario te expones a valores erróneos.
- La tabla  `posicion` debe ser creada primero que `jugador`.
- En la tabla `posicion` debes indicar la restricción `UNIQUE` para la columna `des_posicion`
- En la tabla `jugador` debes indicar que la columna `id_posicion` es llave foránea.

El modelo de datos quedaría entonces así:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    id_usuario SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    usuario VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    contrasena VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    tipo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    estado BOOLEAN
);

INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario, contrasena, tipo, estado) VALUES('admin','123','administrador',TRUE);
INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario, contrasena, tipo, estado) VALUES('AMLO','135','administrador',TRUE);
INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario, contrasena, tipo, estado) VALUES('cisco','456','invitado',TRUE);
INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario, contrasena, tipo, estado) VALUES('hansolo','789','invitado',TRUE);

SELECT * FROM usuarios;

CREATE TABLE posicion(
    id_posicion SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    des_posicion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);


INSERT INTO posicion(des_posicion) VALUES('portero'),('defensa'),('medio'),('delantero');

CREATE TABLE jugador(
    id_jugador SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    apellidop VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    apellidom VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    fecha_nac DATE NOT NULL,
    id_posicion INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_posicion) REFERENCES posicion (id_posicion)

);


INSERT INTO jugador(nombre, apellidop, apellidom, fecha_nac, id_posicion) VALUES('Cristiano','Ronaldo','dos santos','1985/02/05',4);
INSERT INTO jugador(nombre, apellidop, apellidom, fecha_nac, id_posicion) VALUES('Francisco Guillermo','Ochoa','Magaña','1985/07/13',1);
INSERT INTO jugador(nombre, apellidop, apellidom, fecha_nac, id_posicion) VALUES('Neymar','Da silva','Santos','1995/02/05',3);
INSERT INTO jugador(nombre, apellidop, apellidom, fecha_nac, id_posicion) VALUES('Sergio','Ramos','Garcia','1986/03/30',2);
INSERT INTO jugador(nombre, apellidop, apellidom, fecha_nac, id_posicion) VALUES('Arturo','Vidal','Pardo','1987/05/22',2);
```

Y para relacionar posiciones y jugadores harías algo como esto:

```
SELECT 
    j.id_jugador, 
    j.nombre,
    j.apellidop,
    j.apellidom,
    j.fecha_nac,
    p.des_posicion
FROM jugador j 
    INNER JOIN posicion p ON j.id_posicion=p.id_posicion;
```

Obteniendo:

```
id_jugador  nombre      apellidop   apellidom   fecha_nac   des_posicion
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           Cristiano   Ronaldo     dos santos  05.02.1985  delantero
2           Francisco   Ochoa       Magaña      13.07.1985  portero
3           Neymar      Da silva    Santos      05.02.1995  medio
4           Sergio      Ramos       Garcia      30.03.1986  defensa
5           Arturo      Vidal       Pardo       22.05.1987  defensa
```

---

### Datos de prueba

Aquí puedes ver una <kbd>**[DEMOSTRACIÓN](http://rextester.com/CEWMX13429)**</kbd> y hacer pruebas con los datos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, creo que las alertas que te envía Postgresql son bien claras.
En el primer caso, como la columna `id_jugador` es PK, y al no tener una secuencia creada este se generará como nulo, ya que no le das ningun valor en el insert. Tendrás que crear una secuencia para esta columna en vez de darle el type `SMALLINT` lo defines como `serial`.

En el segundo caso la tabla `posicion` tiene solo 2 columnas, y en el insert le estas entregando solo 1 que es la descripción, pero en el VALUES le entregas 4 valores.

Si tu intención era agregar como un solo valor debió ser así

`INSERT INTO posicion(des_posicion) VALUES('portero');
INSERT INTO posicion(des_posicion) VALUES('defensa');
INSERT INTO posicion(des_posicion) VALUES('medio')
INSERT INTO posicion(des_posicion) VALUES('delantero');`